# How to know the exact name which represent a thing in Dbpedia?

Tags: rdf, sparql, semantic-web, dbpedia, linked-data

i have developped a php application which connect to dbpedia to get properties and topics of a thing (name of artist, name of a place, a noun....) 
let's take an exemple:
supposing i want to know the genre or occupation of Michael jackson:

```
    select distinct ?string where {
  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Michael_Jackson> dbpprop:occupation ?string .
}
```

The question is: how to make a full text queries in dbpedia. I mean just by writing a thing it return me the corresponding concept.

Thank you

Comment: DBpedia has many of the same redirect links that wikipedia does, so you may have to follow those.  It's also worth looking at the `owl:sameAs` links.  E.g., look at all those listed in http://dbpedia.org/page/Michael_Jackson.  See [3. Denoting or Naming “things”](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/Datasets#h338-3) in the DBpedia documentation.

Comment: Duplicated at http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/28303/how-to-know-the-exact-name-which-represent-a-thing-in-dbpedia

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor can you please explain more ? I did not understand what you told me. How  to to find that automatically? Thank you

Comment: DBpedia simply inherits the naming from Wikipedia.  There's no deterministic algorithm that's guaranteed to find what you're looking for. It's necessarily going to be a heuristic.  Your best bet is probably to look for resources that have a given `rdfs:label`.

Comment: so what kind of queries i have to write?, the problem is about the queries, I have to use contains in my queries?

Comment: If you want to modify this question, please do so by editing the question using the "edit" link.  Show some examples of the kind of inputs that you're receiving from users.  In general, this is a very difficult problem (what happens if a user types "Mikal Iackson"?) and you may well want to use an external tool to help resolve user input strings to Wikipedia article titles.

Comment: but i dont understand why you still talk about wikipedia

Comment: DBpedia is a big RDF dataset automatically generated from Wikipedia data.  (That's why it's called DB **pedia**.)  The naming convention for DBpedia resources is simply that they're generated from the Wikipedia article title.  If you can find the appropriate Wikipedia article name, then you can generate the corresponding DBpedia resource URI.  As to "how to make a full text queries in dbpedia. I mean just by writing a thing it return me the corresponding concept,"  there's not a whole lot you can do, to be honest.  SPARQL supports regular expressions, and text searches, but if you don't know…

Comment: …the label of a resource, you're going to have a hard time finding it.  Regular expressions over the whole dataset will take a long time.

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look at the data for http://dbpedia.org/resource/Michael_Jackson, you'll see that there's a property `rdfs:label` with the value "Michael Jackson"@en.  You could retrieve the resource with a SPARQL query like the following (I've added the bit about `a owl:Thing`, since you're looking for things, as opposed to categories):

```
select ?s where { ?s rdfs:label "Michael Jackson"@en ; a owl:Thing }
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=select%20%2a%20where%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20?s%20rdfs%3alabel%20%22Michael%20Jackson%22@en%20;%20a%20owl%3aThing%0D%0A%7D&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

SPARQL does support a REGEX operator (it's described clearly in the standard, [*SPARQL 1.1 Query Language*](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/)), but it's probably too expensive to query over everything in DBpedia, and your query will probably time out if you try to use it.

Since DBpedia resource URIs are generated from the corresponding Wikipedia article URIs, your best bet is probably to use a Wikipedia lookup tool and generate the DBpedia resource URIs from the Wikipedia article URIs that you find.

Comment: thanks, but if the searched "word" return many results? for example there is many persons called michael jackson or the searched "word" have many senses ?

Comment: That's an important question.  If you can't do that by hand though, there's not really any hope to do it automatically, though, right?  That is, if there are many results, how would the user know which to pick?  If it's only by things that are in the user's mind, then you won't be able to do it automatically.  If the user has to look at the list and then pick one, you'll need to show such a list to the user and let them pick one.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [DBPedia Lookup Service](https://github.com/dbpedia/lookup).

Comment: but this is coded in java, i'm looking for something coded in PHP.

Comment: Why do you care ? the DBpedia lookup service is just a REST API, you call a lookup URL (like http://lookup.dbpedia.org/api/search/KeywordSearch?QueryClass=place&QueryString=berlin) from your client language of choice, be it Java, PHP, Python, whatever.

Comment: ok thanks. But how to get back the returned result? It show the result in navigator. What if i want get it in a file?

Comment: secondly, how to use the result, i mean how to make disambiguation? if the requested word is apple, how to know what is the right word that the user want?

Comment: I think you should ask separate questions. Do you know how to call a URL using PHP ? how to parse an XML document ? how to implement an suggestion widget to let the user select the preferred result ?